# Jest timesout when testing express app using supertest for 404 route and dynamic routes too

Tags: node.js, express, jestjs, supertest

I'm trying to build an npm package that is an express app where you pass and array of routes that will be used by the app.

The issue that I'm having is that jest timesout/fails when I try to test the 404 route or one of those routes from the array passed in the parameters. When I test a default `/health` route the test passes.

This is the repo https://github.com/byverdu/http-server

```js
// app.mjs
import express from 'express'
import { healthRouter } from './routes/health.mjs'

function expressApp ({ routes } = {}) {

  const app = express();

  app.use('/health', healthRouter);

  for (const { path, handler, method } of routes) {
    // Register all the handlers
    app[method](path, handler)
  }

  app.use((req, res) => {
    res.status(404).send(`No handler found for ${req.url}`)
  })

  return app;
}

export { expressApp }
```

```js
// server.mjs
import { expressApp } from './app.mjs'

function httpServer ({ port, routes } = {}) {
  const PORT = port || 3000
  const server = expressApp({ routes })

  return server.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log(`App running on: ${PORT}`)
  })
}

// usage
const routes = [
  {
    method: 'get',
    path: '/some-path',
    handler: (req, res) => {

      res.send('ok')
    }
  }
]

httpServer({routes})
```

```js
// Tests
import request from 'supertest'
import { expressApp } from '../src/app.mjs'

describe('App', () => {
  it('should have a /health route by default', async () => { // Test passes
    const app = expressApp({ routes: [] })
    const resp = await request(app).get('/health')

    expect(resp.ok).toEqual(true)
    expect(resp.type).toEqual('text/html')
    expect(resp.text).toEqual('ok')
  })

  it('should handle 404 requests', async () => { // Test timeouts
    const app = expressApp({ routes: [] })
    const resp = await request(app).get('/notFound')

    expect(resp.status).toEqual(404)
    expect(resp.type).toEqual('text/html')
    expect(resp.text).toEqual('No handler found for /notFound')
  })

  it('should register all routes passed', async () => { // Test timeouts
    const routes = [{ method: 'get', handler: (req, res) => { res.json({ value: 100 }) }, path: '/someRoute' }]
    const server = expressApp({ routes })

    const resp = await request(server).get('/someRoute').send()

    expect(resp.ok).toEqual(true)
    expect(resp.type).toEqual('application/json')
    expect(resp.body).toEqual({ value: 100 })
  })
}
```

The thing is that I get 2 different outputs on the terminal depending if I run jest on wath mode or not

[image: failing tests on watch mode]

[image: failing test without watch mode]

I tried to increase the tiemout on the jest config but doesn't work either

```json
"scripts": {
    "test:dev": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --watch --detectOpenHandles",
    "test": "node --experimental-vm-modules node_modules/jest/bin/jest.js --collect-coverage --detectOpenHandles --forceExit"
  },
"jest": {
  "testRegex": "(/__tests__/.*|(\\.|/)(test|spec))\\.(mjs?|js?)$",
  "transform": {},
  "moduleFileExtensions": [
    "mjs",
    "js"
  ],
  "testTimeout": 30000 // no luck with it
}
```

Any ideas would be appreciated... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Solved the issue, the problem was that I was defining some middlewares before the routes that were messing with the tests